# Can I add a EFI boot partiton to a disk containing an installation of Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, efi

I recently upgraded the HDD in my desktop, I left my old disk attached  as I wanted to copy the files across. I booted from my Windows 10 installer USB key and installed Windows to the new disk. Everything was working fine.

I've since removed the old disk so I could re-purpose it and of course I didn't test booting my desktop without the disk before I formatted it. Now my desktop won't boot as there's no EFI boot partition on the remaining disk. There's a 16MB "MSR (Reserved)" partition and the Primary partition consuming the rest of the space on the disk.

Is there a way I can add the EFI boot partition to this disk without having to nuke it and start from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed such issue before, and I used GParted. I ran it from under Ubuntu Linux  running from a live CD.

If you willing to use this, do the following:

STEP 0: have a backup that you trust (e.g. tried to restore the system from it before and it worked).

Other, less important steps:

- Boot up from a Windows installer, and got to the "Troubleshoot" menu, and start a cmd shell.
- Issue "chkdsk /r c:" from that shell to fix any possible issues with the filesystem that could prevent GParted from successfully resizing the partition.
- Shut down the machine and boot up a fresh Ubuntu Linux Desktop installer. Make sure it's the 64 bit version.
- Select "Try Ubuntu" insted of "Install". A desktop session will start without installing anything to the machine.
- Hit the Windows key, and type GParted. A single icon should appear. Use the "down arrow" key to select the icon and press "enter" to start the program (or just click on it.)
- GParted will start.
- Make sure the correct disk is chosen from the dropdown menu near the top-right hand corner of the window.
- Use the GUI to resize / move any partitions that might necessary, and create the new EFI partition. Make sure to choose the right partition type and format the partition to FAT32
- Choose "apply all operations" from the "edit" menu to actually write the partition table.
- Wait for GParted to finish operations. This can take a long time. If power fails, you WILL end up with an unusable system. Have your backup ready.

If everything goes well, you'll have your new partition and can use the Windows installer to install the OS loader.

Answer (score 1):

In broad terms, you need to:

1. Resize one or more partitions on the new disk to make space for a new [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) I recommend making the ESP 550 MiB, so this should be the amount of space freed. Moving the end of a partition is safer and faster than moving the start.
2. Create a new ESP in the freed space. Ensure that it uses a FAT32 filesystem and has the ESP type code.
3. Copy all the files from the original disk's ESP to the new disk.
4. Create a new EFI NVRAM boot manager entry to point to the `EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi` file on the new ESP. This part of the process *might* occur automatically when you first boot with only the new disk; or you might need to do it manually from the firmware's setup utility or by using a tool like `bcfg` in an EFI shell, `bcdedit` in a Windows emergency environment, or `efibootmgr` in a Linux emergency disk.

The details of how to do all of this depends on the partitioning and EFI boot manager manipulation tools you use. If you run into problems with any of these steps, you should look for relevant questions about the specific tools or problems you're having, or post a new question about those tools or problems.

Comment: 550MiB for an EFI partition?  Why so large???

Comment: Some EFIs have problems with FAT16 filesystems and/or with FAT32 filesystems smaller than 512MiB. These problems are rare, but they're difficult to correct without increasing the size of the partition. Because of MB-vs-MiB confusion and the fact that `mkdosfs` changes its default from FAT16 to FAT32 at some peculiar value slightly over 512MiB, I recommend 550MiB. That's big enough to ensure you'll get a FAT32 filesystem.